# Retrieve the Organisation detail and email detail of a specified number from contact list of an android phone?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have a phone number. I want to know the detail of that phone number from my phone contact . For that number i stored name, organisation, phone number(work), phone number(home), email(home), email(work), address.

I can get the Display name and ID of that number using the following code

```
Uri lookUpUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(incoming_number));
    Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(lookUpUri,null,null,null,null);
if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        while(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
}}
```

But i do not know how to retrieve the other details .

Please help me out .
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 2 step process:

1. Get the contact-id from the phone number
2. Get requested data types (emails, phones, etc.) from the contact-id

Notes: 

* multiple contacts may have the same phone number, in this example, i'll just take the first contact-id returned, and ignore the rest

* make sure you import all the following classes from `ContactsContract` or `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds`

```
// Step 1:
Uri lookUpUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(incoming_number));
String[] projection = new String[] { PhoneLookup.CONTACT_ID, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(lookUpUri,projection,null,null,null);
if (cur.moveToFirst()){
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    Log.d(TAG, "found contact: " + id + " - " + name);

    // Step 2:
    String selection = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + id + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
    String projection = new String[] { Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1, Data.DATA2, Data.DATA3 };
    Cursor cur2 = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null); 
    while (cur2 != null && cur2.moveToNext()) {
        String mime = cur2.getString(0); // email / phone / company
        String data = cur2.getString(1); // the actual info, e.g. +1-212-555-1234
        int type = cur2.getInt(2); // a numeric value representing type: e.g. home / office / personal
        String label = cur2.getString(3); // a custom label in case type is "TYPE_CUSTOM"

        String kind = "unknown";
        String labelStr = "";

        switch (mime) {
            case Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
                kind = "phone"; 
                labelStr = Phone.getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, label);
                break;
            case Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
                kind = "email";
                labelStr = Email.getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, label);
                break;
            case Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
                kind = "company";
                labelStr = Organization.getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, label);
                break;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "got " + kind + " - " + data + " (" + labelStr + ")");
    }
    if (cur2 != null) {
        cur2.close();
    }
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "contact not found");
}
cur.close();
```

Comment: Thanks but it is displaying details of all contacts ...  i want detail of a specific  number . for that what will be the query . I have the CONTACT_ID

Comment: whoops, see the new selection in step 2, should work now